# Facebook IFrame APP using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook

I have been trying to work on a facebook IFrame app using Asp.NEt MVC and have not been that successful with it. Tried using the samples from facebook SDK however  tags does not get recognized during development. Can some one share the code or point me to a working or preexisting facebook APP sample that would be of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I abstracted away everything directly related to facebook in the Debug config my local machine. The Release config contains the facebook related stuff. I use Unity for DI, so I have DEBUG conditionals that configure different concrete implementations of interfaces.

```
#if DEBUG
            LifetimeManager lifetimeManager = new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager();
            container.RegisterType<ISteamRepository, MockSteamRepository>(lifetimeManager);
            container.RegisterType<IFacebookContextSettings, MockFacebookContextSettings>();
#else
            container.RegisterType<ISteamRepository, SteamRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IFacebookContextSettings, FacebookContextSettings>();
#endif
```

My project is open source, you can see more at http://code.google.com/p/facebooksteamachievements/